# how to get client side confirm box value to make server side operations?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using Client script for confirm message box as follows

```
 string script = "fadeScript";
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, script.GetType(), "Script", "Closewindow();", true);
```

java script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Closewindow() {
        var Result = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
        alert(Result);
        if (Result == true) {
            document.getElementById('txtConfirmresult').value = Result;//assigning to hidden text box 
            alert(txtConfirmresult.value);
        return true;
        }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('txtConfirmresult').value = Result;//assigning to hidden text box 
        alert('BYE');
         return false;
        }
}

</script>
```

I want to use the script return value in .cs file to excite procedure if it returns true. if it return false i have to stay on that particular page only. plz kindly help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__doPostBack(target, argument)` to post back to the server.  You can then evaluate `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` in the post data to see what you sent back and perform logic appropriately.  [Here is a link that provides a little more in depth information](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/).

A quick example:

Script/Client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Closewindow() {
        var Result = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
        alert(Result);
        if (Result == true) {
            var txtConfirmResult = document.getElementById('txtConfirmresult');
            txtConfirmResult.value = Result;//assigning to hidden text box 
            alert(txtConfirmresult.value); //displaying for debug purposes
            __doPostBack( 'txtConfirmresult', Result ); //sending back to server.
        return true;
        }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('txtConfirmresult').value = Result;//assigning to hidden text box 
        alert('BYE');
         return false;
        }
}
```

C#

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string target =  Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
        string argument = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

        if (target != null && target.Equals( "txtConfirmresult" ) )
        {
             this.DoSomeGreatServerSideProcessing(argument);
        }
    }
```

Updated to add slightly more correct variable names, but should work with your existing codebase assuming your script was working.  I would be very careful using `txtConfirmresult` as your ID as that will only work if `runat="server"` is not set on the textbox.  If that is the case, the ID will be prepended to denote container hierarchy.

I would suggest naming your "callbacks" very well, such as:

Script/Client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Closewindow() {
        var Result = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
        document.getElementById('txtConfirmresult').value = Result;//assigning to hidden text box 
        if (Result) {

            __doPostBack( 'UserConfirmedFormSubmission', "CloseWindow" ); //sending back to server.
            return true;
        }
        else 
        { 
           return false;
        }
}
```

C#

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string target = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
        string argument = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(target) && target.Equals("UserConfirmedFormSubmission"))
        {
             if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(argument) && argument.equals("CloseWindow"))
             {
                this.HandleUserRequestedCloseWinow();
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply Torres can you explain me how to use these with an example

Comment: ok torres it is working fine when i write this in button click event it is not working any suggestion for this.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information?  What are you attempting to do?  Can you either ask a followup question and link if its unrelated or update your current question to include the click event handler code you're using?